# How to organize patch files? Many files or a single one?

Tags: patch, organization

What is the best way to organize the patch files? Imagine you have a patch file for an open source application and you modify it and want to keep the modifications in a patch.

What is the best solution: add the new modifications to the other patch in order to have a single big patch file or create the second patch file and have a bunch of them one for each modification.

If you choose the second one, what about patchs that modify the same files and lines and therefore can cause conflicts while patching? Do i have to stablish an order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One patch per issue posted to the projects issue tracker. Otherwise, keep your changes in Git or whatever and use a branch for major projects. Often I have a branch for each module, then a branch for each patch that I'm working on.

Comment: Yes but i'm modifying an open source external tool that i wouldn't like to have in the repository, i want to just have the patches to apply them to the original source code of the external tool.

Comment: We use a separate patch directory for patches that we can't contribute back, but these are pretty rare. I would still try to keep them separate if possible and combine if you have some patches stepping on each other's toes.

Comment: Also, it may be worth trying to get it onto Github or something so you can fork but still make your own changes easily. Then at least you can have your personal fork or personal branch if you're doing the github integration